# Fork GitHub repo and make private bitbucket repo, and use cocoapods with private pod

Tags: git, github, cocoapods

**The problem:**

I want to fork an open sourced Github library and push the same into my private bitbucket repo. However once I push it to my private repo, I should be able to download from my private repo using cocoapods.

**What I did so far:**

So far I did the `bare clone` of the original library and pushed it to my private repo. I'm able to make changes, commit to it. However I'm confused when it comes to the cocoapods part. This is because I want to pull/merge any updates/bug-fixes happening on the public library in future.

So what I need is maintain my private repo and also pull updates from the public repo, if any in future. No worries about the merge conflicts, I'll solve them by my own.

The repository I cloned already has a `podspec` file, how should I configure/modify this file so I can achieve the above or best of both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to modify the podspec file.
You can just add your pod to your podfile like this:

```
pod 'myPod', :git => 'git@bitbucket.org:MyName/myPod.git'
```

Then just run `pod install` and you're ready to go.